# What must be the file system on AWS EBS Multi-Attach volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I'm back again with a new question: What must be the file system on AWS EBS Multi-Attach volume?

On this website https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ebs-access-volumes-using-multi-attach/

It is written that **standard file systems such as XFS, EXT3, EXT4, and NTFS aren't designed to be simultaneously accessed by multiple servers or EC2 instances**.

However, they have not written what must be the file systems for AWS EBS Multi-Attach volume.

Any idea? I would be glad if you can provide the command lines for setting the file system.

Comment: In this blog, (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-multi-attach-for-provisioned-iops-io1-amazon-ebs-volumes/) in the comments, Nathan Neulinger  has written that
"... people MUST use a cluster safe filesystem like GFS, OCFS2, or similar. Deployments using clustered LVM are also possible, though with same caveat about the filesystem used within the volume group."

Comment: Meanwhile, I have used efs which is working properly up to now. Various ec2 instances can read and write from efs simultaneously. Quiet good. I recommend efs solution instead of ebs.

Comment: The EFS solution is significantly slower for systems with many small files, high IOPS than EBS. e.g. An EFS system with 20,000 small 5KB files, a tar operation is like 5 minutes and on EBS it is 200ms.

Comment: The link in the comment to https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-multi-attach-for-provisioned-iops-io1-amazon-ebs-volumes/ doesn't mention anything about GFS anymore.

Comment: Yeah, the docs just say what isn't supported and nothing about what is supported, so I guess it is like launching a product that people need and a bit hands off about what people want to do with it.

Comment: I did find this comparison slidedeck (but didn't find the video) from Gang He at OpenSuse comparing GFS (RedHat) and OCFS2 (OpenSuse, Oracle etc) here https://www.slideshare.net/dchg2000/comparison-between-ocfs2-and-gfs2.

Answer (score 4):

On this page it's very briefly mentioned that a clustered file system is necessary:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes-multi.html#working

In this blog post they explain how to use one clustered file system, the Red Hat Global File System 2 (GFS2), with Multi-Attach EBS. Cluster software must additionally be installed:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/clustered-storage-simplified-gfs2-on-amazon-ebs-multi-attach-enabled-volumes/

Full-Disclosure: I have not actually replicated their results. It was too much overhead for my use case.